# judicial deference

Tags: constitutional-law, legal-terms

I was reading about [judicial deference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judicial_deference) and it discusses about how the courts can defer their decision to another party (i.e., legislative or executive branch).

Is that just another way of punting the decision to someone else?

Comment: Your link is to judicial **deference** which is a very different thing than judicial **reference.** Which do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Judicial deference means that the courts won't interfere with some other decision maker's decision.